# Delete row if its changed status

Tags: sql

I have table :

```
userId, projectId, statusId, date
1           1          1      2020-05-01
1           1          2      2020-05-28
2           5          1      2020-06-01
3           7          2      2020-05-17
```

So for user = 1 and project = 1 status changed from 1 to 2, but in db I have two records.
I need to remove first line user = 1 and project = 1 and statusId = 1

result should be :

```
userId, projectId, statusId, date

1           1          2      2020-05-28
2           5          1      2020-06-01
3           7          2      2020-05-17
```

How can I do it in sql?

Comment: Can you try updating row instead of creating new one.

Comment: Please explain the logic for "removing the first line".  Tables are *unordered sets*, so there is no "first" anything.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you really want the most recent date for each `userId`.  So, one method is filtering:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.userId = t.userId);
```